# How to access array key values of given array structure in php?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array which is coming using `print_r($variable)` in php. I want to modify this array to come in some another form. How can I achieve this.

```
Array
(
    [body] => Array
        (
            [label] => Body
            [widget] => Array
                (
                    [type] => text_textarea_with_summary
                    [settings] => Array
                        (
                            [rows] => 20
                            [summary_rows] => 5
                        )

                    [weight] => 31
                    [module] => text
                )

            [settings] => Array
                (
                    [display_summary] => 1
                    [text_processing] => 1
                    [user_register_form] => 
                )

            [display] => Array
                (
                    [default] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => hidden
                            [type] => text_default
                            [settings] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [module] => text
                            [weight] => 0
                        )

                    [teaser] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => hidden
                            [type] => text_summary_or_trimmed
                            [settings] => Array
                                (
                                    [trim_length] => 600
                                )

                            [module] => text
                            [weight] => 0
                        )

                )

            [required] => 
            [description] => 
            [id] => 6
            [field_id] => 2
            [field_name] => body
            [entity_type] => node
            [bundle] => article
            [deleted] => 0
            [default_value] => 
        )

    [field_tags] => Array
        (
            [label] => Tags
            [description] => Enter a comma-separated list of words to describe your content.
            [widget] => Array
                (
                    [type] => taxonomy_autocomplete
                    [weight] => -4
                    [settings] => Array
                        (
                            [size] => 60
                            [autocomplete_path] => taxonomy/autocomplete
                        )

                    [module] => taxonomy
                )

            [display] => Array
                (
                    [default] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => taxonomy_term_reference_link
                            [weight] => 10
                            [label] => above
                            [settings] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [module] => taxonomy
                        )

                    [teaser] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => taxonomy_term_reference_link
                            [weight] => 10
                            [label] => above
                            [settings] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [module] => taxonomy
                        )

                )

            [settings] => Array
                (
                    [user_register_form] => 
                )

            [required] => 
            [id] => 7
            [field_id] => 3
            [field_name] => field_tags
            [entity_type] => node
            [bundle] => article
            [deleted] => 0
            [default_value] => 
        )

    [field_image] => Array
        (
            [label] => Image
            [description] => Upload an image to go with this article.
            [required] => 
            [settings] => Array
                (
                    [file_directory] => field/image
                    [file_extensions] => png gif jpg jpeg
                    [max_filesize] => 
                    [max_resolution] => 
                    [min_resolution] => 
                    [alt_field] => 1
                    [title_field] => 
                    [default_image] => 0
                    [user_register_form] => 
                )

            [widget] => Array
                (
                    [type] => image_image
                    [settings] => Array
                        (
                            [progress_indicator] => throbber
                            [preview_image_style] => thumbnail
                        )

                    [weight] => -1
                    [module] => image
                )

            [display] => Array
                (
                    [default] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => hidden
                            [type] => image
                            [settings] => Array
                                (
                                    [image_style] => large
                                    [image_link] => 
                                )

                            [weight] => -1
                            [module] => image
                        )

                    [teaser] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => hidden
                            [type] => image
                            [settings] => Array
                                (
                                    [image_style] => medium
                                    [image_link] => content
                                )

                            [weight] => -1
                            [module] => image
                        )

                )

            [id] => 8
            [field_id] => 4
            [field_name] => field_image
            [entity_type] => node
            [bundle] => article
            [deleted] => 0
        )

)
```

I want it to come as:

```
Array
(
  [body]=>Body
  [field_tags]=>Tags
  [field_image]=>Image
)
```

How can I achieve this using foreach loop.
This array is coming from below code.

```
$serialize = field_info_instances('node',$form_state['values']['displays']['selected']);
    foreach ($serialize as $key => $value) {
        print_r($serialize);die;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite array saving keys but change value to label item

```
$newarray = array_map(function($i) { return $i['label']; }, $array);
```

Comment: awesome.Thanks a lot. I didn't get how it worked internally, but yes it solved my purpose. If you can explain it a little for my knowledge, it will be highly appreciable.

Comment: array_map calls function which is the 1st it's argument, giving it values of array. In you case they will be sub arrays pointed by 'body', 'field_tags' and 'field_image'. We take label item in return statement. This value will replace subarray, saving the old key.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `key ()` as it returns the key value from an array index. Please read up on this function [over here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)

Here an example from this page:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'fruit1' => 'apple',
    'fruit2' => 'orange',
    'fruit3' => 'grape',
    'fruit4' => 'apple',
    'fruit5' => 'apple');

// this cycle echoes all associative array
// key where value equals "apple"
while ($fruit_name = current($array)) {
    if ($fruit_name == 'apple') {
        echo key($array).'<br />';
    }
    next($array);
}
?>
```